# Sum of total >90 days divided by total

Tags: sql, summarize

First post, so hopefully this goes well.  I am trying to summarize
some values. I have tried following code.

```
select t1.ar_date_string,
       t1.sum(amount) / (select sum(t1.aMOUNT) 
--from V_CUBE_F_PB_TRANSACTION_AGE pba1 where AR_DATE_RANGE='Current AR' )
from t1
where t1.AR range='historical AR' and t1.days out>90
group by t1.ar_date_string, t1.payor


payor   ar date string  AR range    days out    amount
walm    9/13/2021       current           80    $100.00 
lowes   8/31/2021     historical         100    $100.00 
jcp     8/31/2021      historical       120      $50.00 
belk    8/31/2021       historical       50     $80.00
```

My apologies for delay was having trouble with images and such.
Would like percentage on each row per payor.
Thanks again all,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Y3H.png)

Comment: Hi, Can you add more detail? Are you getting any errors? What is your expectation?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please explain how `150`/`230` is determined.  It is quite unclear.  Do you want one value per row?  Or some sort of summary over the entire table?  Your query is not syntactically correct and the data has more columns than the query returns.  I'm confused.